# Excel Formula needed for the Sum of a Cumulative Group placed in one cell

Tags: excel-formula, sum, grouping

I have two columns. I need the sum of column 2, in one cell, of a new column 3, if the cells (x and x+1) in column one are equal.

This cell must be in the first cell, top of the group, with the other cells blank.

```
ID, Number, Sum_formula
e, 3, 11
e, 3, 
e, 3,
e, 2, 
u, 5, 5
r, 1, 5
r, 2, 
r, 2, 
w, 6, 20
w, 4, 
w, 3,
w, 2,
w, 1,
w, 2,
w, 1, 
w, 1,
```

Here is my attempt, but it only works for a group size of 2:

The ID groups are different sizes. Also this doesn't work for the first group. (I could do the first one manually)

Cell C6 formula
`= IF(A6 = A5, "", SUM(B6,B7))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your IDs are not sorted, there can be many groupings of the same ID, put this formula in C2 and copy down the length.

```
=IF(A2<>A1,SUM(B2:$B$1040000)-SUM(C3:$C$1040000),"")
```

One note:  It will not produce the correct results until the whole range is filled with the formula as it relies on the output of the formulas below it to get the correct result.

[image]

---

If your ID are sorted so that they do not have multiple groupings you can use SUMIF():

```
=IF(A2<>A1,SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B),"")
```

[image]